# skimage inside region centroid

Tags: python, image-segmentation, scikit-image

After image segmentation, for numbering regions, currently, I'm using the `centroid` property of [skimage.measure.regionprops](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.17.x/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=label#skimage.measure.regionprops) which return centroid `xy` of `bbox` of each region, but will return `xy` outside of regions shape like 'c' or similar, also the wrong `xy` for inter-grown regions

My simplified code:

```py
for region in regionprops(label_pixels):
    xy = region.centroid
    x = xy[1] - textWidth
    y = xy[0] - textHeight
    txt= "some text here like regions.label as str"
    draw.text((x, y), txt)
```

How to find `xy` inside all kinds of regions with skimage help or other linear time complexity functions?
Since all I am using is scipy, numpy and skimage, then I prefer not to use opencv here

Any guide would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

That function doesn't exist in scikit-image, but it is one that I've needed as well — specifically in our functions to [draw region adjacency graphs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.17.x/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_boundary_merge.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-boundary-merge-py). I recommend that you create an issue in https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues so we can keep track of this request. I would call this feature the "geodesic centroid", though I'm not sure whether my terminology is exactly correct.

Comment: well,new issue added, btw i can not call this issue instead new function or parameter is a better call, hope they manage it, [github link to the issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5092)

Comment: Haha it would be great if one could call issues. =P Hopefully someone can implement it soon. Note that if you implement it, with the new skimage 0.18 (release candidate is out now, release probably Monday), you can pass your implementation in as a custom regionprop.